# admin no longer has access to shared folder

Tags: 12.04, command-line, virtualbox, shared-folders, guest-additions

So over the weekend I arrive to work, boot my PC and run the virtualbox session of Ubuntu but now I get the message:

> The folder contents could not be displayed
>   You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "sf_virtual"

I don't understand what could have happened?  I did install an update and read an article to re-install `Guest Additions` and it still doesn't allow access in `/media`.  When I do `gksudo nautilus` and then `sudo ls -al /media/sf_virtual` it will display all the files in virtual as `-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf numbers month date time filename`.  When I am under name in the terminal `ls /media/sf_virtual` it returns `Permission denied`. Any ideas on how to get access back?   I have removed the shared folders and added new ones but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your user is no longer a member of the vboxsf group - you can check by using the `id` command in a terminal or `getent group vboxsf`

If that's the case, you can add the user back with

```
sudo gpasswd --add <username> vboxsf
```

or the equivalent `adduser` or `usermod` command

You will probably need to log off and back on for the change to take effect

Comment: I faced the same problem, when I try to add the user it says `gpasswd: group 'vboxsf' does not exist in /etc/group`

Comment: @qurban Have you installed the VirtualBox [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) ?